# Tkinter. Scrollbar is not working on Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I am newbie in programming, don't hate me pls :)

Why scroll is not working on my canvas widget?
I added loop with 30 rows and I cannot scroll down.
Its look like it because of create_text() method or maybe not.
I've written code for example below.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x150')
frame = Frame(root)

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL)
yscrollbar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT)

canvas = Canvas(frame,
                yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set,
                bg='white')
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH)
yscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

n=12
for i in range(1,31):
    canvas.create_text(10,n,text=i)
    n+=12

frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: my code]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling is not responsive because you need to tell the canvas to limit the scrolling to a given area.

You can use the `bbox` method to get a bounding box for a given object, or a group of objects.

`canvas.bbox(ALL)` returns the bounding box for all objects on the canvas.

Link: http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm you can check other methods to do this in this link

Here is the working code:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x150')
frame = Frame(root)

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL)
yscrollbar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT)

canvas = Canvas(frame,
                yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set,
                bg='white')
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH)
yscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

n=12
for i in range(1,31):
    canvas.create_text(10,n,text=i)
    n+=12

frame.pack()

# Add this line to tell the canvas the area over to scroll
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))

root.mainloop()
```